# Accessing a dynamic field from another field template in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-data, asp.net-dynamic-data

Is there a way to access the value of a dynamic field from another dynamic field template?

For example let's say that in my model I have something like this:

```
//auto generated by my data context
partial class Foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldGenerateNameDynamically { get; set ; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(FooMetadata))]
partial class Foo{}


class FooMetadata
{
    [UIHint("DynamicName")]
    public object Name { get; set; }
}
```

So based on the value of `ShouldGenerateNameDynamically` I'd like to *enable or disable* and assign a calculated value to the `Name` field in my custom **`DynamicName`** template either in the `PreRender` or `OnDataBinding` events

So is there any way to send like an event across the dynamic data templates or access another field from a field template?

Comment: I do this with DB triggers.